# Is sending customer data via Javascript (post messages) forbidden from security perspective?

Tags: javascript, security, post, postmessage

We have a child iframe (3th party) which wants to communicate with the parent (my account section). The iframe sends facebook id and receive registered user phone number. If we follow all post message security checkpoints like:

- configuring the targetOrigin on both side
- checking event.origin for both iframe and parent
- sanitize the input in order to not allow xss atacks (script tags)
- checking if the messages in a specific format (json and with some specific keys)
- checking if the user is authenticated on parent side

are there any other security concerns that can make this method unsuitable for sending customer sensitive data?

Comment: Use HTTPS. To address the title - no, otherwise you literally cannot send customer data in any way. HTTPS should be your first idea, so you don't send data in plain text, thus it cannot be (easily) intercepted and captured.

Comment: @vlaz although you are of course right that HTTPS should be used for any data that is transported between the client and the server(s), this isn’t directly related to postMessage (that one is purely client-side, at this point there is no data leaving the client already.)